# Automatically Trigger Automator through mail

Tags: mail.app, automator

I want to trigger a workflow in automator every time I receive a new email in "mail.app". How can this be done?

Comment: Probably best done with a folder action.

Comment: @mehmenmike What is a folder action? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Read the first couple of paragraphs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html)

Comment: This is NOT best done with folder Actions. Maybe @mehmenmike can explain why they think that is the case??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can:

You can use the normal Mail rules with a perform action: Run Applescript.

Create a normal  Mail rule applescript. But include code to call your automator workflow via the unix command [/usr/bin/automator](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/automator.1.html).

The **/usr/bin/automator** command will run the workflow you point it at and optionally can pass input  onto the workflow using the -i option.

Here is a quick example of a Applescript Mail rule which gets the subject of the email/s and runs a automator workflow that speaks any text passed on to it. In this case the email subject.

The script MUST be saved in: your `~/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail`  folder for mail.app to see them.

> You can attach a script to a Mail rule. For example, you could have an
>   incoming message trigger a script that copies information from the
>   message and pastes it into a database that works with AppleScript.
>
> Choose Mail > Preferences, then click Rules. Add a rule or select an
>   existing rule to edit.
>
> Choose Run AppleScript from the “Perform the
>   following actions” pop-up menu.
>
> Choose a script from the pop-up menu
>   of scripts that are located in ~/Library/Application
>   Scripts/com.apple.mail.
>
> Or choose “Open in Finder” to open the folder
>   so you can copy a script into the folder first.
>
> If you later move or rename the
>   script, your rule will not work.
>
> Click OK to save the rule.

[image]

---

The example Applescript for the Rule

(Change the  **workFlowPath** property to reflect the full path to your Automator workflow file)

```
property workFlowPath : quoted form of ("/Users/YourUserName/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/mailSpeakTest.workflow") --CHANGE THIS TO YOUR FULL WORKFLOW FILE PATH example  "/Users/joeblogs/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/mailSpeakTest.workflow"


    using terms from application "Mail"
        on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
            repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
                (*Get the email Subject *)
                set input_Argument to subject of eachMessage
                (*Run subroutine for workflow *)
                my runAutomator(input_Argument)
            end repeat
        end perform mail action with messages
    end using terms from

    (*Workflow  Subroutine *)
    on runAutomator(input_Argument)

        (*Path to workflow *)


        (*Setup and Run the unix command *)
        set command to "/usr/bin/automator   -i " & quoted form of input_Argument & space & workFlowPath
        do shell script command
    end runAutomator
```

The Automator workflow is simply

[image]

Comment: I have done all the steps that you have done above but was not able to get any result. Now, the path that you mentioned "/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/mailSpeakTest.workflow" does not exist in my OS X Mavericks. I went with the closest path "/Library/Scripts/Mail Scripts" and saved my script there. Also, is it required that I save my workflow file there too? Also just to clarify, will this script automatically start my workflow every time I receive an email in my Mail app without my notice as that is exactly what I want to achieve. Thanks in Advance @markhunte

Comment: @kevin You just need to change USERNAME to your username. And mailSpeakTest.workflow to what ever you name your workflow, You can save your workflow anywhere. I just did it there for convineance of being with the applescript file. And yes mail rules run as long as mail is running.

Comment: @kevin i have update the code for clarity and also the post

Comment: Thank you!! This really made my day. Thanks for the clear explanation. @markhunte